# Change command depending on file extension/type

Tags: vimrc, functions

I usually work with php projects and phpunit. I've mapped `<leader>T` thus I can run tests.

```
# my .vimrc file portion
nnoremap <Leader>T :!vendor/bin/phpunit --filter
function! RunFilteredTests()
    let l:filter = input('Filter test with ... ')
    exec ':!php ./bin/phpunit --filter ' . l:filter . "\<CR>"
endfunction
```

Lately, I've started to play with `golang`. Can I use same shortcut with different behavior depending on the current open file?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Sure, you can use the `FileType` autocmd.

```
" Set the default behavior
nnoremap <Leader>T :!vendor/bin/phpunit --filter

" Now set it if we open a go file
autocmd FileType go nnoremap<buffer> <Leader>T :call GoFunction()
```

You can, of course, change `go` to whatever filetype you want. If you're not sure what filetype to use, open the file that you want it to work in and type `:set ft?`. This will tell you what filetype your file is.

See [`:help :autocmd`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/autocmd.txt.html#%3aautocmd), [`:help FileType`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/autocmd.txt.html#FileType), and [`:help <buffer>`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/map.txt.html#%3Amap-%3Cbuffer%3E) for more info.